# Shell script to list the files which are a specific size range

Tags: linux, shell

Question is to list all the files in a directory which are in a specific size range.
I'm able to check the sizes all the files in the directory but the if statement is not able to use the $FILESIZE as an integer to check its range.
Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt
do 
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$i")
echo "$FILESIZE"
if [ 9 -lt $((FILESIZE)) -gt 10 ]
then 
echo "$i"
fi
done
```

Output:

[image]

Edit:
Got it

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.txt
do 
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$i")
val=$((FILESIZE))
if [ $val -gt 9 ]
then 
if [ $val -lt 21 ]
then
echo "$i"
echo "size of $i is $val"
fi
fi
done
```

Thanks

Comment: `[ 9 -lt $((FILESIZE)) -gt 10 ]` -- what do you think that will do?

Comment: (Include error messages as **text** in your question, not an image)

Comment: Why not use `find` with the `-size`-flag? [find man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html#top_of_page)

Comment: What range are you trying to check? There's no integer that's greater than 9 and less than 10.

Comment: You miss an "and" operator: "if [filesize -gt xx AND filesize -lt yy] ..."